# View error didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am working for a view in django, I am currently working on a model form:  I check if student is already created, if it is created I will just update info for that student and I add entry to certain event if necessary; if not I create a student and add entry to event.

The webpage works fine in the case where I create a new student which is in except for the first try, but when I try to get student that already exists the page gives me error of didn't return an HttpResponse object. Can you help me please?

```
def reserve(request, event_id):
  event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = StudentForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
      try:
        student = Student.objects.filter(UID=form.cleaned_data['UID'])
        #student.first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        #student.last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        msg = 'Student found, added to reserve for this event!'
      except Student.DoesNotExist:
        student = Student.objects.create(UID=form.cleaned_data['UID'], first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'], last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'])
        msg = 'Contact created, reserve successful!'

      obj, created = Reservetoevent.objects.get_or_create(m_event=event, m_student = student)
    return render(request, 'events/reserve.html', {
      'form': form,
      'event': event,
      'msg': msg,
    }) 
  else:
    form = StudentForm()


    return render(request, 'events/reserve.html', {
      'form': form,
      'event': event,
    })
```

Comment: Are you posting via ajax or a regular full page post?

Answer (score 0):

Your `form.is_valid():` is false. Because the last return you have on there is in the `else` (meaning the request.method == "GET"), there is no response.
Move your last return to the left. And that should fix it. But it won't fix the reason your form is not valid.

```
def reserve(request, event_id):
  event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = StudentForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
      try:
        student = Student.objects.filter(UID=form.cleaned_data['UID'])
        #student.first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        #student.last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        msg = 'Student found, added to reserve for this event!'
      except Student.DoesNotExist:
        student = Student.objects.create(UID=form.cleaned_data['UID'], first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'], last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'])
        msg = 'Contact created, reserve successful!'

      obj, created = Reservetoevent.objects.get_or_create(m_event=event, m_student = student)
    return render(request, 'events/reserve.html', {
      'form': form,
      'event': event,
      'msg': msg,
    }) 
  else:
    form = StudentForm()


return render(request, 'events/reserve.html', {
  'form': form,
  'event': event,
})
```